# Toshiba Laptop battery issues

Tags: laptop, battery, power, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite S75 laptop. The laptop was fine until a week or so ago. Initially, there was a blinking orange light a few days before that only happened once. I am not sure if that's a factor.

The issue is that the laptop won't charge at all even though its plugged in and indicates as such. In addition, each day I turn on the laptop, it loses some battery life like ~3-5%, even though it doesn't drain any life while its on. Occasionally it would not drain if I plug in charger for a while before I turn it on, but only not drain once or twice from when I tried it.

I was wondering if its a battery issue. I bought a new charger, but doesn't seem to have solved the problem at all.

I was wondering if it's a battery failure, motherboard failure,or just out of date bios (2014).

If its bios then I tried, but I don't have enough battery to update it because the lowest is 20% and I am at 6% at the moment.

Comment: how old is this battery ??

Comment: The battery is 6 years old

Comment: then its probably the battery, in my opinion you will have to get a new battery.

Comment: you can still try this before throwing the battery :https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-restore-a-dead-or-dying-laptop-battery/
But DON'T freeze if it is Lithium Ion battery.

Comment: try this link too : https://www.wikihow.com/Revive-a-Dead-Laptop-Battery

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you mentioned that the battery is six (!!) years old in the comments, this is most likely a case of the battery dying from old age. Consider replacing the battery with a new unit.